# Swiping left to go back in swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

This is how my storyboard is set out:

[image]

And I want to be able to swipe left and right within view controllers. However I am not using segues, I am changing view controllers programatically. I also need to be able to not swipe back to the sign up and log in pages from the home page.

How do I do this?

I'm not sure if it is necessary however the code I am using the change view controllers is:

```
let codeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.codeViewController) as? CodeViewController
view.window?.rootViewController = codeViewController
view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

**EDIT**

I understand I should not use the code above and should use Segues, however I have to change the view programatically from the sign up and login pages. And I cannot have 2 Navigation Controllers so what do I do?

Comment: What is the swipe? Is it a swipe animation from right to left? Than in your start viewcontroller you can do

```let codeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.codeViewController) as? CodeViewController

navigationController?.pushViewController(codeViewController!, animated: true)```

Comment: @Oleksandr No, the other way around, going back a view controller

Comment: "the code I am using the change view controllers is" Well, that's the problem. Don't do that. You should not be replacing your root view controller on the fly. That isn't navigation. Even without segues you can push onto a navigation controller, and there you are, all set.

Comment: @matt how do you do that? I knew that was the problem but I wasn't sure how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `UISwipeGesture` and add the animation for it.

```
let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
swipeDown.direction = .down
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
```

If you want to `paging` functionality, you can utilize a `UIPageViewController`. [Here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/) is a basic example regarding `UIPageViewController`.